Amplify Cognito redirectSignOut doesn't work
I'm developing a Vite/React with Amplify Cognito for authentication.
I have a main page that redirects to sub-applications, and I would like every sub-application redirected to the main page for login & logout. Amplify Cognito is integrated into both main & sub-applications.
For example, what I want :

login on the main page -> go to application A -> logout on application A -> go to the main login page.

While for now, it's :

login on the main page -> go to application A -> log out on application A -> stay to app A login page.

I don't understand how to use the redirectSignOut value, when I log out, it doesn't redirect to the redirectSignOut, it stays to the current URL with the Cognito login page displayed.
export const authConfig: ResourcesConfig['Auth'] = {
  Cognito: {
    userPoolId: XXXX,
    userPoolClientId: XXXX,
    identityPoolId: XXXX,
    allowGuestAccess: true,
    signUpVerificationMethod: "code", // 'code' | 'link'
    loginWith: {
      oauth: {
        domain: XXXX,
        scopes: ["email", "username", "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"],
        redirectSignIn: [https://login_url],
        redirectSignOut: [https://logout_url],
        responseType: "token"
      }
    },
  }
};

The URL https://logout_url is not used when I log out.
I also added this https://logout_url into my AWS Cognito configuration: User pool / App integration / App client / Allowed sign-out URLs.
What am I missing?
